# Cognos Chart filtering

Tags: cognos, cognos-10

I made the pie chart clickable in active report and linked to data deck and to filter on lists but the thing here if it's possible to multi select on chart and how to make it reset to show all items I can't make it anti select so it show all as when it loaded

anyone faced that before

Comment: Your question is confusing. Please read stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask and rephrase your question.

Answer (score 0):

I think I understand what you are trying to do here.

You appear to be trying to set the value of a filtered pie chart in an active report to be unfiltered, or similar to a case where you have "selected all"

The simplest way to do this is to create a button that will set the variable filtering the chart to empty. Since you are not filtered all values will be shown.

[Source](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEP7J_10.2.2/com.ibm.swg.ba.cognos.ug_cr_rptstd.10.2.2.doc/t_specfy_react_behavr.html%23specfy_react_behavr)